# error: Super must be first statement in constructor

Tags: java

cannot figure out why i am getting this error. Working in Notepad, running javac through cmd (obviously more to the file). If you need me to link more i can.
My error is happening at "setCruiseShip" where i am trying to link the current to the super class.
error: Call to super must be first statement in constructor.

```
class Ship
{ protected String name;
  protected float speed;
  protected int year;

  public Ship() {name=""; speed=year=0;}
  public Ship(String n, float sp, int y) {name=n; speed=sp; year=y;}
  public String getName()  {return name;}
  public float  getSpeed() {return speed;}
  public int    getYear()  {return year;}
  public void   setShip(String n, float sp, int y) {name=n; speed=sp; year=y;}
  public String toString() {return "Ship named "+name+ " with max speed of " 
                           +speed+ " was built in " +year;}
}

class CruiseShip extends Ship
{ protected int maxpass;

  public CruiseShip() {super(); maxpass=0;}
  public CruiseShip(String n, float sp, int y, int mp) {super(n, sp, y);
                                                        maxpass=mp;}
  public int  setMaxpass(int mp) {maxpass=mp;}
  public void setCruiseShip(String n, float sp, int y, int mp){super(n,sp,y);
                                                               maxxpass=mp;}
  public String toString() { return super.toString() +" carries "
                            +maxpass+ "  passengers";}
}
```

Comment: use separate .java file for both the classes and also make the classes public classes.

Comment: `setCruiseShip` is not a constructor, so it can't call the `super` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`class Ship` has no method named `setCruiseShip`. What you probably want is to call the `setShip` method. Replace

```
super(n,sp,y);
```

with

```
setShip(n,sp,y);
```

Comment: @user2155992 If it is the right solution, kindly mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Super constructors can be called only from the constructor of the child class(not from any method).  Modified and compiled program given below

```
class Ship {
    protected String name;
    protected float speed;
    protected int year;

    public Ship() {
        name = "";
        speed = year = 0;
    }

    public Ship(String n, float sp, int y) {
        name = n;
        speed = sp;
        year = y;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public float getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setShip(String n, float sp, int y) {
        name = n;
        speed = sp;
        year = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Ship named " + name + " with max speed of " + speed
                + " was built in " + year;
    }
}

class CruiseShip extends Ship {
    protected int maxpass;

    public CruiseShip() {
        super();
        maxpass = 0;
    }

    public CruiseShip(String n, float sp, int y, int mp) {
        super(n, sp, y);
        maxpass = mp;
    }

    public int setMaxpass(int mp) {
        maxpass = mp;
    }

    public void setCruiseShip(String n, float sp, int y, int mp) {
        setShip(n, sp, y);
        maxpass = mp;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " carries " + maxpass + "  passengers";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer, select that as the answer by clicking the Tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

`super(somevalues...)` can be called from subclass's constructor. Java doesn't allow to call `super(somevalues...)` from methods. Also when you define constructor in subclass then its first statement should be either `super()/super(somevalues)`  constructor or `this(somevalues...)`. If you don't do this then compiler implicitly add default no-arg super constructor.

`this()`  means constructor overloading.
and the given fact is

```
public void setCruiseShip(String n, float sp, int y, int mp){super(n,sp,y);
```

is not a constructor in subclass.

Constructor `definition` is, constructor name must (I am not saying 'should') be same as class name with no return type and any access modifier is allowed(like private, default,protected,public).

so `setCruiseShip` is not as same as `CruiseShip`